# Read a strcut with a struct array inside, from a binary file in C

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles

I'd like to read a binary file which is composed of struct, and these struct are also composed of a struct array.

This is my two struct :

```
typedef struct view
{
    long CustomerID;
    int Rating;
    char Date[11];
}View;

typedef struct movie
{
    long MovieID;
    long YearOfRelease;
    char Title[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    long CountView;
    View *Views;
}Movie;
```

And I'd like to have something like this:

```
void readDataFromBinary()
{
    FILE *f = NULL;
    f = fopen("../saved_data/save_data.bin", "rb");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Movie movie;

    while(fread(&movie, sizeof(Movie), 1, f) != 0)
    {
        printf("MovieId : %ld\n", movie.MovieID);
        printf("YearOfRelease : %ld\n", movie.YearOfRelease);
        printf("Title : %s", movie.Title);
        printf("CountView : %ld\n\n", movie.CountView);

        for (int i = 0; i < movie.CountView; i++)
        {
             printf("%ld\n", movie.Views[i].CustomerID);
             printf("%d\n", movie.Views[i].Rating);
             printf("%s\n", movie.Views[i].Date);
        }
    }

    if (fclose(f) == -1)
    {
        perror("fclose");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

The function is good for `MovieID`, `YearOfRealease`, `Title` and `CountView` without the `for` loop, but for the components of `Views`, I have a `core dump`...

Comment: You cannot save or read structures with pointers inside just so.

Comment: Yes, because you've written an entirely arbitrary pointer to a `Views` into your file. You'll need better serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply write a pointer into the file and expect to be able to read it back just like that; instead you'll need to serialize your data into the file, for example like this (untested, etc., etc., don't trust this blindly):

```
void write_view(View *view, FILE *file) {
  fwrite(&view->CustomerID, sizeof(long), 1, file);
  fwrite(&view->Rating, sizeof(int), 1, file);
  fwrite(view->Date, sizeof(char), 11, file);
}

void write_movie(Movie *movie, FILE *file) {
  fwrite(&movie->MovieID, sizeof(long), 1, file);
  fwrite(&movie->YearOfRelease, sizeof(long), 1, file);
  fwrite(movie->Title, sizeof(char), MAX_LINE_SIZE, file);
  fwrite(&movie->CountView, sizeof(long), 1, file);
  for (int i = 0; i < movie->CountView; i++) {
    write_view(&movie->Views[i], file);
  }
}
```

Then, similarly, you'd read the "header information" for the movie, allocate memory for enough `Views`, and then call a `read_view()` function to populate them.

Comment: Ok thanks ! I'm gonna try this